# How to install NVIDIA Nsight Eclipse Edition without CUDA toolkit?

Tags: eclipse, cuda, nsight

I would like to install NVIDIA Nsight Eclipse Edition on Ubuntu without installing unneeded dependencies from the CUDA toolkit.

I know that nsight uses `nvvc` and some other libraries from the toolkit, but would that be possible to have a minimal copy of nsight without having to duplicate ALL of the cuda system repository ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are on Ubuntu you can install it like `sudo apt-get install nvidia-nsight` and I think this gives you just nsight eclipse edition.

Another approach would be to take a copy of nsight from a full cuda install and then uninstall cuda.  I just looked under /usr/local/cuda/libnsight and this looks like a full eclipse install folder.  Maybe just copy this directory to somewhere else, and remove /usr/local/cuda.

Comment: Thx, copying the libnsight and the jre folder made it. works perfect !